# Why the element shows again when I hide it using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview, updatepanel, linkbutton

I have a listview control in web page and in listview, I have a LinkButton. My LinkButton inside updatepanel control. When I click on LinkButton, Counter field +1. I use ClientIDMode="AutoID" for my page does not full postpack. Now, I want when click on LinkButton, display of LinkButton be equal 'none'. For this, I use script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTextArea() {
    $('.like').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(updateTextArea);
</script>
```

Now, my problem is: When i click on LinkButton, LinkButton is hide and show again. Where is my fault. Please help me. Thank a lot.

This is my aspx code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="PortfolioListView" runat="server" onitemcommand="PortfolioListView_ItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li class="item brick1 <%# Eval("CategoryName")%> isotope-item">
                        <a class="item-popup" href="Gallery/195x195/<%# Eval("MainImage") %>" title="<%# Eval("ShortDesc") %>">
                            <img src="Gallery/195x195/<%# Eval("MainImage") %>" alt="<%# Eval("Title") %>" />
                            <div class="hover">
                                <span class="Popup"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></span>
                                <span><%# Eval("CategoryName")%></span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <div class="title"><span><%# Eval("Title")%></span></div>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="like"><asp:LinkButton ID="LikeLBTN" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" OnClientClick="updateTextArea()" CommandName="Like" CommandArgument="<%# Bind('GalleryID') %>"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i><span><%# Eval("Counter")%></span></asp:LinkButton></div>
                            </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you inspect element and see? Does `display: none;` exists or gets overridden or something?

Comment: When i click on LinkButton, display:none added to tag and then it will be removed.

Comment: `it will be removed` - Why? Who? Where?

Comment: Add a return false in your OnClientClick to avoid postback `<div class="like"><asp:LinkButton ID="LikeLBTN" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" OnClientClick="updateTextArea();return false;" CommandName="Like" CommandArgument="<%# Bind('GalleryID') %>"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i><span><%# Eval("Counter")%></span></asp:LinkButton></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happing due to auto-post feature of asp.net controls.Update your java-script function, rest code will same.

```
function updateTextArea() {
        $('.like').on('click', 'a', function () {
            $(this).hide();
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Comment: With return false, LinkButton is hide and it is not show again. it is good but when i click on linkbutton, Should one be added to the number of like (Counter field). number of like save in database and with CommandName="Like" in listview, i update this field. When i use return false in script, update command in code behind does not work. is there another solution? Tnx.

Comment: if this is a case then you go with aspx.cs file to handle hide or other event